# Why does receiving a Mandrill email take so long (sometimes)?

Tags: smtp, gmail, email, mandrill

I use Mandrill for sending emails via SMTP, however, sometimes it can take a long time, as in 30-60minutes, before I receive my email.

If I look into the Outbound-list, it lists my emails as 'delivered', yet I often have to wait quite a bit before I actually see it in my inbox.

It seems to be mostly when I send to gmail and yahoo, but this could be just a coincidence.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the message is released from your ESP(Mandrill) it has not been processed by the recipients ISP server yet. This can take up to 48 hours to process, but usually only takes minutes. The ISP delay is caused by things such as large attachments or file size, large volume from same domain, large influx of messaging hitting server at same time, error in email header, etc.

[More info](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)